# Interface 'App\additional\IManage' not found

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-5.8

I am trying to create interface then implementing it so I created folder inside the app folder called "additional" and created inside it file called IManage.php inside it the following:

```
<?php 
namespace App\additional;

interface IManage{

publice function manageCycle(int $c):void;

}
```

then I created a file called manage.php inside the "additional" folder as follow:

```
<?php 

namespace App\additional;

class Manage implements IManage{

public function manageCycle(int $c){

echo $c;

}
```

but when I try to call the create new object of the Manage class and call manageCycle method inside any controller function I get:

> "Interface 'App\additional\IManage' not found"

how to solve this please?

Comment: Remove `.php` from the interface name: `interface Imanage {`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter sorry it was typo in question

Comment: Also, you have casing differences between `IManage` and `Imanage`. Change the interface to `interface IManage{` and run `composer dumpautoload`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some typo errors and there is return type issue I solved please check this

IManage.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

interface IManage
{
    public function manageCycle(int $c);
}
```

Manage.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Manage implements IManage
{

    public function manageCycle(int $c){

    }
}
```